# using javascript fetch API with a SOAP web service

Tags: javascript, reactjs, soap, fetch-api

I'm having a really rough time POST'ing to a SOAP web service using the fetch API. I worked out my CORS issues using a chrome plugin, but now it seems to be having an issue with the format of what I'm sending. I've tried implementing fixes I see in other questions, especially in Content-Type and whatnot, but I cannot get any different result. It just plain does not like a < in slot 1.

Based on other questions, the actual 'data' that I am sending does look a little different from other SOAP requests... they mention an Envelope, they define an XML version, etc. Mine is the pure XML data I send in a SOAP service tester here locally. So I guess what I don't know is whether that software is adding additional details to the request 'payload' before sending it to the service.

The WSDL is not very helpful, but I might be looking in the wrong spot.

Any advice is highly appreciated.

My Javascript/fetch:

```
var base64 = require('base-64');

let url = 'http://SCRB4APUSLSA801:9080/apex/services/argobasicservice';
let username = 'abo055';
let password = 'hidden';
let headers = new Headers();

export const N4RecordScan = {

    submit(data) {

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        headers.append('SOAPAction', 'basicInvoke');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.encode(username + ":" + password));

        let dataPrefix = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:arg="http://www.navis.com/services/argobasicservice"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><arg:basicInvoke><arg:scopeCoordinateIds>APMT/USLAX/LAX/LAX</arg:scopeCoordinateIds><arg:xmlDoc><![CDATA[';
        let dataSuffix = ']]></arg:xmlDoc></arg:basicInvoke></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';

        data = dataPrefix + data + dataSuffix;

        console.log('about to send ' + data);

        fetch(url, {
            body: data,
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: headers,
            credentials: 'include'
        })
            .then(response => console.log(response))
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        //.done();

    }
};
```

This is what I'm sending in data:

```
<gate><record-scan><gate-id>USLAX</gate-id><stage-id>asd</stage-id><lane-id>asd</lane-id><external-console-id>asd</external-console-id><truck tag-id="asd" license-nbr="asd"/><equipment><container eqid="asd" on-chassis-id="asd" /><chassis eqid="asd"></chassis></equipment></record-scan></gate>
```

This is the response I'm getting:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<soapenv:Fault>
<faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
<faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.</faultstring>
<detail>…</detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this is the WSDL for the service I'm reaching out to.

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.navis.com/services/argobasicservice" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="ArgobasicService" targetNamespace="http://www.navis.com/services/argobasicservice">
<wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Argo Services</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.navis.com/services/argobasicservice">
<xsd:element name="basicInvoke">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="scopeCoordinateIds" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="xmlDoc" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="basicInvokeResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="basicInvokeResponse" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="invokeRequest">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="scopeCoordinateIds" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="request" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="handler" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="locale" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="invokeResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="basicInvokeResponse" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="basicInvokeRequest">
<wsdl:part element="tns:basicInvoke" name="basicInvoke"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="basicInvokeResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:basicInvokeResponse" name="basicInvokeResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="invokeRequest">
<wsdl:part element="tns:invokeRequest" name="invokeRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="invokeResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:invokeResponse" name="invokeResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="ArgobasicServicePort">
<!--  name of your wrapped method  -->
<wsdl:operation name="basicInvoke">
<wsdl:input message="tns:basicInvokeRequest"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:basicInvokeResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="invoke">
<wsdl:input message="tns:invokeRequest"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:invokeResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="ArgobasicServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:ArgobasicServicePort">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<!--  name of your wrapped method  -->
<wsdl:operation name="basicInvoke">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="invoke">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="ArgobasicService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:ArgobasicServiceSoapBinding" name="ArgobasicServicePort">
<soap:address location="http://scrb4apuslsa701:10080/apex/services/argobasicservice"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
( function(){ window.SIG_EXT = {}; } )()
```

Comment: 1. Please fix your code sample. Minimum effort. Did you copy-paste a diff?

Comment: 2. SOAP is xml, and you're sending JSON-related headsers. 3. You are indeed missing a `<?xml version="1.0"?>` line.

Comment: @Evert Corrected code and updated to what I have after spending loosely 8 hours at work on this. I ended up using SoapUI to try and see a real submission that works... and that gave me the <? you show as well as the construction my WSDL is actually seeking. The good news is that the first submission actually works now! But if I click my submit button any more for additional submits, they all fail w/ bad credentials error from the SOAP. If I reload my page, again.. first works, all subsequent fail.  Any ideas?

Comment: Glad to see you made it a lot further! I don't have an answer to this new question though :(  I wonder if you need to do `let headers = new Headers();` every time (move it into the function body).

Comment: small note, unrelated to your problem. Everywhere you currently use `let`, you should use `const`. But yea this has no bearing on the outcome

Comment: Ok I'm actually somewhat sure it's the headers, because you keep appending to the same set of headers and set a larger set of headers for every request ;)

Comment: @Evert That was it. Moved the headers declaration into the function and it now works beautifully. Do you want to post as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're re-using the same `Headers` object for each request. Which means that you're tacking on new Authorization headers every time you're doing a new request.

Move the `let headers = new Headers();` into the function body (and use `const`), to probably make it work!